# discord.py add_roles function not working

Tags: discord.py

Attempting to create a jail bot that sends user to the "APOS zone" when given the role "APOS", but the bot is unresponsive when the command is sent

```
import os
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
import keep_alive
from discord.utils import get

Bot_Token = os.environ['Bot_Token']

bot = discord.Client()

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='AGOP~')

#startup
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  guild_count = 0

  for guild in bot.guilds:
    print(f"- {guild.id} (name: {guild.name})")
    guild_count = guild_count + 1

  print("AGOP_Bot is in " + str(guild_count) + " guilds.")

#APOS
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_role("APOS")
async def APOS(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    role = get(user.server.roles, name="APOS")
    await user.add_roles(user, role)
    await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has been sent to the shadow realm")

bot.run(Bot_Token)
keep_alive.py
```

Comment: As @Fien has answered, you probably would want to replace `user.server.roles` to `user.guild.roles`. If you are going to fetch the roles using the `get` function, you won't need `role` as a parameter as well.

Comment: You're defining a command under `Bot`, but then you are running `bot`. The command will not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

The `discord.Member` class doesn't have a `server` attribute. `user.guild.roles` is what you most likely are looking for. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member

Comment: replacing discord.Member with user.guild.roles would create a name error though, since the variable would be referenced before being defined

Comment: @destructer77, `user.server.roles` is to be changed to `user.guild.roles` and not `discord.Member`